# Chernoff Bound for Normal Distribution

Tags: probability, upper-lower-bounds

I've come across a question that firstly asks to derive the moment-generating function of a random variable $X \sim \mathrm{Normal}(\mu, \sigma^2)$ as 
$$
M_X(t) = \exp\left(\mu t + \frac{\sigma^2t^2}{2}\right),
$$
which is fairly straightforward. Then, it asks to derive the following bound on the probability that $X$ exceeds a certain value:
$$
\forall \delta > 0 . \mathbb{P}(X \geq (1+\delta)\mu) \leq 
\exp\left(-\frac{d^2\mu^2}{2}\right)
$$

Now, I make the following attempt:
$$
\begin{align}
\mathbb{P}(X \geq (1+\delta)\mu ) & \leq \min_{t \in \mathbb{R}}\left(
\frac{\exp\left(\mu t + \frac{\sigma^2t^2}{2}\right)}{\exp((1+\delta)\mu t)}\right) \\
\\ & = \min_{t\in \mathbb{R}} \left(\exp\left(\frac{\sigma^2t^2}{2} - \delta t \mu\right)\right) \\ \\
&\stackrel{\mathrm{def}}{\equiv} \min_{t\in \mathbb{R}}(f(t))
\end{align}
$$
Now, optimising over $t$ gives:
$$
\begin{align}
&& \frac{\partial f}{\partial t} &=  f(t) \cdot (\sigma^2t-\delta \mu)\\
\therefore && \frac{\partial f}{\partial t} = 0 &\implies t= \delta\mu\sigma^{-2}
\end{align}
$$
Thus, the tightest bound that can be derived using Markov's inequality with the mgf is 
$$
\forall \delta > 0 . \mathbb{P}(X \geq (1+\delta)\mu) \leq 
\exp\left(\frac{\delta^2\mu^2}{2\sigma^2}-\frac{\delta^2\mu^2}{\sigma^2}\right)
=\exp\left(-\frac{\delta^2\mu^2}{2\sigma^2}\right)
$$

This, however, is only a tighter bound than the desired one if $\sigma^2 \leq 1$, which is not specified in the question.

Is this because the question is flawed in not specifying this constraint, or is there an alternative strategy than the Markov bound which may be used to obtain the bound?

EDIT: As a commenter pointed out, the bound the question gives cannot hold in general because we can make the given probability arbitrarily high for fixed $\delta$ by setting $\sigma^2$ arbitrarily close to $\frac{1}{2}$. The question is therefore flawed.

Comment: Their bound presumably is implicitly assuming $\sigma^2=1$. The inequality they write does not use $\sigma$ at all, so clearly cannot be valid in general.

Comment: Perhaps a silly question, but you and your stated inequality refer to a “$d$” not a $\delta$, was this a typo in the original statement? If not then just setting $d=\delta/\sigma$ works

Comment: @adfriedman you are right, typo on my end. Sorry, question edited.

Comment: @J.G That's a good point; I had overlooked the obvious fact that by setting the variance arbitrarily high you can make the probability $\mathbb{P}(X\geq(1+\delta)\mu)$ for fixed $\delta$ arbitrarily close to 1. Thanks, question answered.

Comment: Not to nitpick, but you can get it arbitrarily close to $\tfrac12$, not $1$, but the same principle applies.

Comment: @adfriedman yes, you are technically correct---the best kind of correct.  I've changed the post, thanks for pointing this out.